# How to convert a JSON string to an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I convert a JSON string to an object in JavaScript? Is there a method that does this?

Something like:

```
var x = "{  id: 5, name: 'hello'  }";
var y = /*something*/(x);

alert(y.id + " " + y.name);
```

Comment: Without or without frameworks (jQuery etc.)?

Comment: (And please, no `eval`.)

Comment: am i missing something? looks like convert **from** JSON, not to

Comment: I don't have a `JSON` object, I have a `string`, so it's string to JSON.

Comment: @Bruno: It is a string *encoded in JSON*. You want to convert a JSON-encoded string into Javascript objects. (JSON = Javascript Object *Notation*.)

Comment: @Bruno: Also, your string is not in valid JSON syntax.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the comments and question history it look like that you're already using jQuery. In that case, it's good to know that jQuery ships with a new [`parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function since [version 1.4.1](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4.1/) which was released late January this year. Consider upgrading if you're not at 1.4.1 yet. Here's an extract of relevance from its API documentation:

> ***Description**: Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object*.
>
> **jQuery.parseJSON( json )** version added: [1.4.1](http://api.jquery.com/category/version/1.4.1/)
>
> **json** The JSON string to parse.
>
> Passing in a malformed JSON string will result in an exception being thrown. For example, the following are all malformed JSON strings:
>
> - `{test: 1}` (test does not have double quotes around it).
> - `{'test': 1}` ('test' is using single quotes instead of double quotes).
>
> Additionally if you pass in nothing, an empty string, null, or undefined, 'null' will be returned from `parseJSON`. Where the browser provides a native implementation of `JSON.parse`, jQuery uses it to parse the string. For details on the JSON format, see http://json.org/.
>
> **Example:**
>
> Parse a JSON string.
>
> ```
> var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
> alert( obj.name === "John" );
> ```

Comment: BalusC: I won't remove the `jquery` tag, but for future reference, the tags are for the *question*, not the answers. The question does not narrow the choices to jQuery, even if he is open to jQuery. Out of 6 answers, yours was the only jQuery related one. Basically, this is not a jQuery question and should not be tagged as such.

Answer (score 5):

Use json2 lib : http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 2):

Bruno,

here's the jquery method, which as you'll see, uses the self same new Function("return..) business.

```
parseJSON: function (a) {
    if (typeof a !== "string" || !a) return null;
    if (/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test(a.replace(/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, "@")
        .replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, "]")
        .replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, ""))) 
        return z.JSON && z.JSON.parse ? z.JSON.parse(a) : (new Function("return " + a))();
    else c.error("Invalid JSON: " + a)
}
```

**[edit]** the regex is of course 'dealing' with any rogue characters embedded within ther json string.

spooky tho :)

Comment: but it uses JSON.parse where available, which is definitely a Good Thing (tm). Without the JSON object, there is hardly a better way to do the conversion, since making a full JSON parser in JavaScript would surely result in something slower than eval

Comment: ammoQ - yes, absolutely. just glad they didn't use the eval method as the fallback mind you :)

Answer (score 1):

This paragraph fully covers the native JSON implementations, and libraries that use native JSON implementations:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Native_JSON

Using native JSON implementation will be considerably faster/safer than using some javascript libraries for same task. However, if some library claims it will try using native implementation whenever possible - it's even better choice that using native JSON directly (compatibility and stuff).

Answer (score 0):

The JSON.org website gives the simplest solution:

```
var y = eval('(' + x + ')');
```

[More information](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Edit: Oh. Right. The `eval` solution is good if and only if you are sure that you can trust the source to produce correct JSON objects. Otherwise, you will have to use a JSON parser - look at the other replies.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do the following which is slighly less evil than eval :) :

```
var x = '{  "id": 5, "name": "hello"  }';

var y = new Function("return " + x)();
alert(y.id + " " + y.name);
```

tho as said by others, if you're using jquery, go for the inbuilt parseJson method.

Comment: Nice one, but I guess this is as dangerous as `eval`

Comment: Bruno - the mechanics under the covers are different and if you look at the jquery code, you may just see something akin to this in that function (parseJSON: function (a)). see excerpt below for jquery function from source..

Answer (score 0):

The modern answer to this question is to use `JSON.parse`:

```js
var myObject = JSON.parse(
    '{  "id": 5, "name": "hello"  }');
```

All modern browsers have this function built in, and most of them had it built in when the question was first asked.