# Can I use a variable to pass a json string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works:

```
$(this).load($('.pageloadlabel', this).attr('href'), {category: 1});
```

This code doesn't work:

```
var data = '{category: 1}';
$(this).load($('.pageloadlabel', this).attr('href'), data);
```

The question is, how can I make it work?

Comment: Try removing the quotes around the JSON when you assign to data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not a Javascript object but a string, you can convert it to object by eval e.g.

```
data = eval('(' + data + ')');
```

but eval is considered dangerous, so better to parse string as JSON e.g.

```
data = JSON.parse(data)
```

For JSON lib you can use [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)

Comment: I was able to solve my problem using the JSON library. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's not JSON, it's a javascript object.

```
var data = { category: 1 };
```

If you have a string, you would have to [convert it to a object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013839/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-an-object).

And notice that your string is not a valid JSON, see the link for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Take out the quotes, the load function is expecting an object, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `eval()` on data?

```
var data = '{category: 1}';
$(this).load($('.pageloadlabel', this).attr('href'), eval(data));
```